# Why join result reutrns 0 records in Datastage?

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I've got  a join , which the join is from another join and an Oracle Connector

It does kinda looks like this : 
[image]

but the inner join results returns 0 records, which is not how it should be. Because i've made a query before designing the Job and i gave me 5 records.
And i've also make sure and checked that they've got same value.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Maybe it is better to edit your question with dataset values...

Comment: You need to provide more details - how are the link statistics? How many rows are returned from th e first left join?